# How can I include the contents of a PHP file stored in a variable after modifying it's content?

Tags: php

I have a PHP template file,  `index.php`, that has both PHP and HTML in it

If I `include 'index.php';` the file, everything works as expected.

But I want to modify the file before including it, and to that end I've written the following code:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('index.php');

// The position at which the HTML <head> tag ends in index.php
$posHeadEnd = strpos($contents, '</head>');

$linkTag = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/assets/css/main.css' type='text/css'>";

// Insert <link> tag into the contents
$contents = substr($contents, 0, $posHeadEnd) . $link . substr($contents, $posHeadEnd);

include $contents;
```

This function adds a `<link>` tag to the variable `$contents` to add additional CSS.

When it's done it includes the `$contents` variable.

I don't understand the error in the `error_log` file:

```
PHP Warning:  include(&lt;?php
$locale = $this-&gt;Template-&gt;locale;
?&gt;

&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;

&lt;html lang=&quot;da&quot;&gt;

&lt;head&gt;

    &lt;meta charset=&quot;UTF-8&quot;&gt;

    &lt;meta name=&quot;viewport&quot; content=&quot;width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0&quot;&gt;

    &lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-type&quot; content=&quot;text/html;charset=UTF-8&quot;&gt;

    &lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;X-UA-Compatible&quot; content=&quot;IE=edge&quot;/&gt;

    &lt;meta property=&quot;og:title&quot; content=&quot;eDiary&quot;/&gt;

    &lt;title&gt;eDiary&lt;/title&gt;

    
[01-May-2021 15:24:50 Europe/Copenhagen] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '&lt;?php
$locale = $this-&gt;Template-&gt;locale;
?&gt;

&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
```

The error seems to be the content of `index.php` but HTML-character-encoded.

I've tried using the `html_entity_decode` function but that didn't help.

Maybe this is a problem in the `include` function or maybe it's not intended to be used this way?

Comment: PHP's [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function is used to load a separate PHP file into your file, it's parameter should be the path to a PHP file you want to include, not an HTML string. I would suggest reading up on what *include* does, you'll find that it might be better to include index.php and then echo something from that file.

Comment: Just echo `$contents`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use this as a template. If the contents are just HTML, you can echo/print the contents.  If you actually need php code parsed, you may want to think of a different way.

Answer (score 1):

`include` is here to include files. You cannot include strings. Your script tries to include a file with the name of the content of index.php, thats what the warning states:

> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '<?php...

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but probably you should just add that additional `<link>` tag in your index.php. Possible inside a conditional. Something like

```
$needsLinkTag = true;

include index.php
```

and inside index.php

```
...
if ($needsLinkTag) {
  echo '<link ...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this code.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('index.php');

// The position at which the HTML <head> tag ends in index.php
$posHeadEnd = strpos($contents, '</head>');

$linkTag = "<link rel='stylesheet' href='/assets/css/main.css' type='text/css'>";

// Insert <link> tag into the contents
$contents = substr($contents, 0, $posHeadEnd) . $link . substr($contents, $posHeadEnd);

file_put_contents('index.php', $contents, LOCK_EX);
include 'index.php';
```

Comment: But be aware, that this will change the content of `index.php` permanently. Probably not what you want to...

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you but question asker has not mentioned about if he needs permanent change or temporary change....   Another solution is he can replace his last line in his own code from      "include $contents;"     to       "echo $contents;"